# JXTable Incorrect Sorting

Tags: java, swing, sorting, swingx, jxtable

I am using a JXTable to display, filter, and sort some data. However, I'm getting some unexpected behavior when sorting. As you can see, the values are not ascending as expected, but sorted how a string would be sorted.

To address the comments, I am sure this column is getting parsed in the correct part of the code (i.e. the Float.valueOf() block.) I know this through debugging. Also, I am sorting the column by clicking on the jxtable's header. I am not doing it programmatically.

[image: Incorrect Sort Order]

Just to be clear, I am adding them as Floats:

```
class FantasyProTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
   void loadData() throws BiffException, IOException
   {
      Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Input.xls"));
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

      int numCols = sheet.getColumns();
      for(int col=0;col<numCols;col++)
      {
          addColumn(sheet.getCell(col,0).getContents());
      }
      for(int rownum=1;rownum<sheet.getRows();rownum++)
      {
          Object[] row = new Object[numCols];
          for(int col=0;col<numCols;col++)
          {
              try
              {
                  row[col] = Float.valueOf(sheet.getCell(col,rownum).getContents());
                                 //parseFloat() doesn't work either
              }
              catch(NumberFormatException e)
              {
                  row[col] = sheet.getCell(col,rownum).getContents();
              }
          }
          addRow(row);
      }

      workbook.close();
   }
}
```

What can I do to get it to sort in the correct, ascending order, by value?

Comment: Can you provide the `TableModel`?  They appear to be getting treat as `String`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Updated. What I had originally was its body. This is the only function in the class.

Comment: Add a debug statement in you catch clause, make sure that the values are been parsed correctly...

Comment: I already did that (as noted in the question). They are. I'm assuming they're being sorted as a generic Object as opposed to a Float.

Comment: How you are sorting the table? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It's a JXTable, so the function is built-in. I'm just clicking on the column header, not doing it programatically.

Comment: Did a quick test and it seems to be working for me....

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm. The only other thing I am doing is adding it to a JFrame. Strange. Are you sorting it after you display it? It displays right at first (because I am adding them sequentially), but not when you apply the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after much digging, I've found two things, one, `JXTable` has it's own "row sorter", which wraps the default one and two, because `DefaultTableModel` returns `Object.class` by default from `getColumnClass`, these things are getting screwed up (SwingX's sorter is trying to make use of the `Comparator` interface, but if the object class is not comparable, then it defaults to using `toString`)

You have two choices...

## You can...

Implement the `getColumnClass` from `DefaultTableModel` and return a proper class reference...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return Float.class;
    }
};
```

## Or you can...

Provide your own comparator of the `JXTable` row sorter implementation...

```
((TableSortController)table.getRowSorter()).setComparator(0, new Comparator<Float>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Float o1, Float o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, the first option still allows you to sort String columns. These don't get me 100% there, but I can take it from here. Thanks!

Comment: Of course you should return a different class depending on the columnIndex.

Comment: @keuleJ Yup, some minor tweaking and now it works. Thanks MadProgrammer!